# Java Generics calling self class explanation

Tags: java, spring, generics

[Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259109/dave-syer) has wrote following class in the package, `org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.builders`.

```
    public class ClientDetailsServiceBuilder<B extends ClientDetailsServiceBuilder<B>> extends
        SecurityConfigurerAdapter<ClientDetailsService, B> implements SecurityBuilder<ClientDetailsService> {
}
```

I'm having some difficulties understanding this code. Can anyone explain usage of generics here and what Dave is trying to achieve here?

Comment: dave syer would be the most appropriate for this question, try to contact him if no good answer appears

Comment: Judging by this small snippet, I'm guessing it's the fairly common idiom for a fluent builder API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called a *recursive type bound*. Here `B` is defined in terms of `ClientDetailsServiceBuilder`. But since that is the type that is just being declared, `B` appears again to satisfy the type parameter.

A more general explanation that I've found useful: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106

Another good example for this pattern:

```
public interface Tree<T extends Tree<T>> {
    List<T> getChildren();
}
```

This definition makes subtypes (implementations) of `Tree` automatically return children of their type parameter, which has to be a `Tree` and can even be **their actual type**. If the return type was just `List<Tree>`, callers expecting the subtype might have to cast.

Comment: "This definition makes subtypes (implementations) of Tree automatically return children of their actual type." Not necessarily. They return children of the their type parameter, which is not necessarily their actual type.

Comment: You are correct, one `Tree` could have children of another type of `Tree`. I'll change the wording a bit. Also, larger type hierarchies would make things messy here. Just thought this would be an easier-to-grasp example for recursive bounds than the Spring builder stuff.

Answer (score 2):

By using `class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>>` you get access to any subclass' type as a generic type.

This enables you to do things like this:

```
class MyClass<T extends MyClass<T>> {
    private int value;

    T withValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        return (T) this;
    }
}

class MySubclass extends MyClass<MySubclass> {
    private String name;

    public MySubclass withName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}

MySubclass s = new MySubclass()
    .withValue(5)
    .withName("John Doe");
```

Comment: "This enables you to do things like this:" No it doesn't. `(T) this` is unsafe.